# VNAs and different characteristic impedances

Tags: vna

What is the right technique to measure a matching network, cable, etc that is at a different characteristic impedance than 50Ω?

In my case, I need to measure the SWR of a matching network that needs to be 125Ω. However, the SWR on my HP 8753B is of course in relation to a 50Ω Z0. I though I could just set the VNA to a new Z0, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is the solution, after several hours of work. To help with the context, I am using a cold-war era HP 8753B with an 85046B S-parameter test set- and yes, the B-model is 75Ω. And please don't get confused below. This answer is about using a VNA with Z0 that is not 50Ω, but I have to make a few comments about hand-made standards because you aren't likely to find standards in anything other than 50Ω. And I haven't found a way in my VNA to have it interpolate a 50Ω load to some other impedance.

**The mathematics in my VNA (and I assume most VNAs) are based on *scaled values*.** It doesn't *really* know what 50Ω real, or 250Ω real is. And this applies to complex loads as well. All it knows in the world is what it measures from the calibration standards- and please comment where I am wrong below.

Though not actually part of the answer to my question, as I refer to calibration loads below, picture in your mind all the different ways those loads are made. Think about their geometry, and the fact that any adjacent conductors can be capacitors, and any conductor can be an inductor, whether the cal standards you use are:

1. supplied by the manufacturer
2. 3 coax pigtails that start life as identical in **every way possible** especially including the length and how the ends are stripped, before you make them into an open, load and short
3. opened, loaded and short copies of a PCB you need to measure

At any rate, here is what I learned about my question. **When you calibrate a VNA, what you are actually teaching it is what it should call ∞, 1 and 0.** Just like the normalized Smith chart. **There is no magic in 50Ω.** Nowhere in all the complex math on SWR, the Smith Chart, the reflection coefficient, etc. is there a special case for 50Ω, BUT **∞, 1 and 0 are all very special numbers.**

Back to the point. When calibrating the VNA, it is reading the response of what you call an infinite impedance, a characteristic impedance, and 0 impedance.

So, if you are working with a transmitter or receiver that works best at some impedance different than 50Ω, what do you do? There are only 3 steps.

First, calibrate the VNA with your standards, an open, a load at the relavent impedance you need (be it 10Ω, 50Ω or 300Ω), and a short. And again, make your own open, load and short standards carefully- and NEATNESS COUNTS!! You are going to want to trust your readings. Conversely if you trust readings that are actually wrong- in the accented words of my Korean professor "you waste your life". The load should be resistors- preferably something like 0603 surface mount resistors. And make the resistance from at least 2 resistors in parallel, if not 4, to minimize inductance.

Second, looking at the smith chart view, adjust the electrical delay on your VNA so that the ∞ and 0 loads actually read very close to ∞ and 0.

Third, adjust the characteristic impedance (on my VNA this is in the calibration menu) to your actual load resistance. But remember, all you are actually doing is setting the scale value for readings that need it, like the actual impedance readings in the smith chart. BUT, scale values are NOT used on the actual smith graph, nor in the return loss and SWR readings.

Those charts are nothing more than comparisons (actually mathematical difference I think) to the open, load and short standards it read during the calibration sequence.

But now that your VNA is calibrated to your target impedance, all the charts start making sense again.

Below are 3 pictures of readings of a transmitter circuit that I needed a good match for at 319MHz. The MAX7044 is most efficient with a 125Ω impedance. Incidentally (and this is for free), the MAX7044 has an output capacitance of about 5.6pF at 319MHz, which seems to me to be a CRUCIALLY overlooked tidbit of knowledge on the data sheet.

1. the actual swept response of a transmitter and matching network on a spectrum analyzer. Notice the peak on the left at 319Mz, and the peak on the right at about 400MHz. I injected a swept frequency in place of the crystal in the MAX7044 transmitter, and used a coax stub stripped back 1/4" or so as the test antenna so it should hopefully have a flat response at 300MHz to 450MHz.
   [image: Annotated Spectrum Analyzer]
2. the log mag on the VNA calibrated with a **50Ω** load. Notice it says the 400MHz peak is better (which it clearly isn't in the actual circuit), owing to the fact that the circuit is at about 50Ω at 400MHz
   [image: Log Mag of VNA calibrated to 50Ω]
   [image: Smith chart of VNA calibrated to 50Ω]
3. the log mag on the VNA calibrated with a **125Ω** load. Notice the response is a much better prediction of the actual circuit, because the circuit is at about 125Ω at 319MHz- the ideal impedance for the transmitter
   [image: Log Mag of VNA calibrated to 125Ω]
   [image: Smith chart of VNA calibrated to 125Ω]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get it as 125 Ohm resistive when seen through your matching network, put a parallel 83 Ohm mass resistor and tune the system to be 50 Ohm resistive (SWR=1). The resistor should be inserted in the SWR meter side of the matching network.

I admit this is ok only with low power and so low frequency that a parallel resistor is possible without remarkable distortion to the propagation of the wave.

ADDENDUM; You seemingly have no-nonsense equipment. Most of us can only dream of a vector analyzer. Put a passive 50 to 125 ohm matching resistor network to the input of your DUT and a passive 125 to 50 Ohm resistor network to the output of your DUT. The last can be a 125 Ohm resistor, if only the reflection is interesting. You only need to compensate the scalar attenuation of the resistor  networks. That should be practical at least in VHF.

A full vector analyzer for 2 port circuits can gather so much data that even without 50/125 and 125/50 resistor networks the performance should be possible to calculate in complex vector domain as an estimate for "how it would work in a proper 125 Ohm system"

You can do test runs with simple known DUTs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're measuring a one-port device, you can use the VNA as is.

A VNA works by measuring reflection coefficient at its internal \$50\Omega\$. It can display it in a variety of ways, like magnitude or SWR, which are at \$50\Omega\$, but it can also convert it into Ohms for you. These are genuine Ohms, not related to the system \$Z_0\$ at all. *

Here's an example of a Smith Chart on an analyser screen. You don't have to worry how it measured these numbers, This is the actual impedance at the calibration or reference point, at this frequency, as R+jX. **
[image: Markers on VNA]
(From http://www.eryptick.net/unisold/mwmeas.html - take a look at the last graph)

From this complex impedance, you are free to calculate SWR to any other impedance, or reflection coefficient, return loss or S-parameters, from these actual Ohms values.

$$\Gamma = (Z_{meas} - Z_{0new})/(Z_{meas} + Z_{0new}) $$
$${VSWR} = (1+\Gamma)/(1-\Gamma)$$

This does require that you take care of the position of the reference plane or measurement point. While SWR to \$50\Omega\$ is the same at any position in the cable, impedance changes with distance, the 50 ohm cable transforming the non-50-ohm load. For < 100 MHz, just keep the wires shorter than 1 or 2 cm.
If you're measuring up to 1 GHz, it will pay you to take special precautions:
a) make an SMA calibration kit of your own, with Open, Short and Load (two 100 Ohm resistors) all absolutely flat on the back surface of the connector.
b) use similar SMA connectors to connect to your device under test
c) calculate the impedance of the two-wire transmission line between the face of the SMA, and the device under test, and mathematically transform it out of the measured results.
Using these techniques I've successfully measured the complex impedance of small integrated circuits up to 1 GHz.

If you're measuring a two-port device, it's more complicated. The analyser presents a \$50\Omega\$ load to Port 2 when measuring Port 1, so if your system impedance is \$125 \Omega\$, the measured \$S_{21}\$ and \$S_{11}\$ will be incorrect. if it's a linear network, not say an amplifier, you can still fix this with a lot more calculation, but it's a lot harder.

---

\$*\$ But the further the impedance is from \$50 \Omega\$, the less accurate the VNA becomes
\$**\$ But only if you calibrated the VNA with the standards it was expecting - so if it's a 50 Ohm VNA and expects 50 Ohm standards, you need to use these correctly.

Comment: If I calibrate the VNA with 50Ω, then exit calibration and read a 50Ω load it of course reads 50Ω. But if I then set the Z0 of the VNA to 125Ω, it then reads 50Ω as 125Ω, which tells me it is normalizing everything and only applies the relavant scaling when necessary for displaying.

Comment: Granted a precision cal kit will always produce more accurate readings. But are the SWR, log mag, Smith charts, etc. only useful for a 50Ω load? If I'm willing to give up a little accuracy and use my own custom-made cal kit with a characteristic impedance that really matters, (in my case right now 125Ω), the relativley small loss in accuracy is more than made up for by the fact all the charts work again.

Comment: The real test is to carefully handmake a set of standards, calibrate using the pre-programmed cal kit that is closest, and measure a few lump impedances. In my limited experience so far, I can say the error is within an SWR of 1 or 2. Again, granted that may not be precise enough for every application, but has worked very well for me so far. I like to hear from someone else who can try this for themselves.

Comment: @lance all the charts are for 50 Ohms. But the impedance *values* from Smith chart markers are independent of Z0. From what you describe, changing the system Z0 will definitely not help you - the charts still have true 50 at the centre, they just label it as 125, so a 50 Ohm load still shows 1:1 SWR. Good idea to make a ~125 Ohm test standard, use two 270 Ohm resistors perhaps.

Comment: A 50 Ohm analyser should only be calibrated with short, open and load near 50. Of course the standards are not exactly these impedances, so there are parameters stored with the kit, and in fact you can use any known load impedance, just gets less accurate away from 50 Ohms. But these are still true values, the analyser knows the true impedance of each standard. If you lie to the analyser when calibrating, to get the wrong impedance at the centre, all sorts of things will go wrong.

Comment: I agree with you that a VNA with 50Ω input impedance will certainly be at its best at 50Ω. But it seems to me that, to say that is to imply a VNA is only _really_ useful when working with a 50Ω circuit. I thought the whole point of the calibration procedure was to negate the effects of the test cable, connectors, etc of the test so that only the characteristics of the DUT are displayed. Using my handmade standards for 125Ω, the VNA has no problem reading a 50Ω, 22nH or 50pF load within a couple of ohms, pF or nH.

Comment: @lance No I'm not trying to say that. A VNA measures reflection coefficient at 50 ohms, period. But a calibrated (and 50 Ohm) port can measure any impedance, within reason. You're right about calibration, it extends the measurement port right to the end of the cable, removing all other effects along the way. Once you're there, it just measures the S parameters, which it transforms to impedance, using its known 50 ohms. The impedance under test is always different to 50 ohms, otherwise we wouldn't be measuring it:)

Comment: Yea, that came out wrong. What I mean to say is It appears my VNA is working as well when calibrated to 125Ω. As a result, a 125Ω load has an SWR of 1, smith chart is normalized to 125Ω, etc. Again, a precision 125Ω load would be better, but a carefully hand made one is useable.